# Add Background Image and Add Text on the Image

Tags: java, servlets, pdf-generation, itext

I am new to iText Library. My requirement is My Servlet will create an Mark Sheet(PDF). It will add image to the complete page of the document and Text on the specific location on the image of the document.

Please help?

Comment: The book [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/) is a great resource for anyone using iText. You'll also find the sources of all the samples in the book on that web site. Furthermore you'll find 2 important sample chapters on the [publisher's site](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/) to download for free.

Comment: This is my function
`private static void addContent(PdfContentByte canvas, PdfContentByte text, Document document) {
Image img = Image.getInstance("07.png");
img.scaleToFit(PageSize.A4.height(), PageSize.A4.width());
img.setAbsolutePosition(1, 1);
canvas.addImage(img);
canvas.saveState();
canvas.setCMYKColorFill(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80);
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,            BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
text.beginText();
text.setFontAndSize(bf, 18);
text.lineTo(1, 1);
text.showText("This is Test");
text.endText();
document.add(img);}`

Comment: Image is loaded but I am not able to set Text at particular Position

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what the parameter `text` is about. Maybe you picked the direct content that goes under the image, but that's not the main issue.

You must have read some documentation, because you're using `beginText()`, `setFontAndSize()`, `showText()` and `endText()`, but you didn't read the documentation very well because:

(1) You use `lineTo()` without a `moveTo()` first and without a `stroke()` after. In other words: you're creating a strange path that is never drawn.

(2) You use `showText()`, but I don't see you defining coordinates for the text anywhere. What happened to your `setTextMatrix()` method?

(3) You're a newbie, but instead of using simple code, such as:

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
    new Phrase("This is a test"), 100, 100, 0);
```

Seems like you want to be able to run before you've learned to walk.

Also: you're probaly using an old version of iText, because you don't mention that an exception is thrown when you use the illegal statement `lineTo()` inside a text block. You can't use `lineTo()` inside a `beginText()`/`endText()` sequence.

Please follow the advice given by mkl and read the documentation first.